# How to create and save the created thumb in my table using the image manipulation codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have module called Manage Menu, where the admin will add another menu. I used the image manipulation class to make all the sizes is the same. I dont know how to apply it to my system, I just tried it as static and its worked.

**Static**

```
public function index()
    {
        $config = array(
            'image_library'     => 'gd2',
            'source_image'      => 'assets/img/2.jpg',
            'create_thumb'      => 'true',
            'width'             =>  575,
            'height'            =>  550,
        );
        $this->load->library('image_lib',$config);
        $this->image_lib->resize();
```

Question: How can I resize the uploaded image and save it to my table?

**My controller **

```
public function new_menu_form_submit()
    {
        $image = array(
            'image_library'     => 'gd2',
            'source_image'      => 'upload/'.'$this->upload->data("file_name")',
            'create_thumb'      => 'true',
            'width'             =>  575,
            'height'            =>  550,
        );
        $this->load->library('image_lib',$image);
        $this->image_lib->resize();
        $config = array(
            'upload_path'   => 'uploads',
            'allowed_types' => 'jpg|png|PNG|JPG',
            'max_size'      => '2048', //25MB
            'encrypt_name'  => TRUE //encrypt filename
            );

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        if($this->form_validation->run('new-menu') == FALSE) {
            $error = [

                'menu_name_error'         => form_error('menu_name'),
                'menu_price_error'         => form_error('menu_price'),
                'menu_stocks_error'         => form_error('menu_stocks'),
                'menu_image_error'         => form_error('menu_image'),
            ];

            echo json_encode($error);
        }else{
            $uppercase_menu_name = ucwords($this->input->post('menu_name'));

            $menu_name = preg_replace('/(.)(?=[A-Z])/u', '$2', $uppercase_menu_name);
            $insert_menu = [
                'menu_name'               => clean_data($menu_name),
                'menu_price'               => $_POST['menu_price'],
                'menu_stocks'               => $_POST['menu_stocks'],
                'menu_image'               => $this->upload->data('file_name'),

                'status'                    => "Active"
            ];
            $this->Crud_model->insert('menu',$insert_menu);
            echo json_encode("success");
        }
    }
```

**View**

```
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <!-- Breadcrumbs-->
      <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <li class="breadcrumb-item">
          <a href="<?= base_url().'administrator/dashboard'?>">Dashboard</a>
        </li>
        <li class="breadcrumb-item">
          <a href="<?= base_url().'administrator/manage_stocks'?>">Stocks</a>
        </li>
        <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Edit Stocks</li>
      </ol>
      <!-- Icon Cards-->
      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-6">
          <ol class="breadcrumb">
          <div id="success-message-new-menu"></div>
          <form id="new-menu">

            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Name:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="menu_name" id="menu_name">
               <div class="text-message" id="menu_name_error"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Price:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="menu_price" id="menu_price">
              <div class="text-message" id="menu_price_error"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Stocks:</label>
              <input type="number" class="form-control" min="1" name="menu_stocks" id="menu_stocks" >
              <div class="text-message" id="menu_stocks_error"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
               <label>File</label>
              <input type="file" name="menu_image" id="menu_image" class="form-control">
               <div class="text-message" id="menu_image_error"></div>
            </div>

            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success " value="Continue" align="center" ">

          </form>


          </ol>
        </div>






      </div>

    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid-->

    <!-- /.content-wrapper-->
     <!-- Logout Modal-->
        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Ready to Leave?</h5>
                <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">Select "Logout" below if you are ready to end your current session.</div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="<?= base_url(). 'administrator/logout'?>">Logout</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    <footer class="sticky-footer">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="text-center">
          <small>Copyright © Your Website 2017</small>
        </div>
      </div>
    </footer>
    <!-- Scroll to Top Button-->
    <a class="scroll-to-top rounded" href="#page-top">
      <i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i>
    </a>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#new-menu").on('submit',function(e){
        var form = new FormData(document.getElementById("new-menu"));
        $.ajax({
            url: base_url + "administrator/new_menu_form_submit",
            data: form,
            type: "POST",
            processData: false, // tell jQuery not to process the data
            contentType: false, // tell jQuery not to set contentType
            success:function(data) {
                var result = JSON.parse(data);

                if(result === "success")
                {
                    $("h5").html("");
                    success_message("#success-message-new-menu","New Menu Added Successfully!");
                    window.setTimeout(function(){location.href=base_url+"administrator/menu"},2000);

                }else{

                    $("#menu_name_error").html(result.menu_name_error);
                    $("#menu_price_error").html(result.menu_price_error);
                    $("#menu_stocks_error").html(result.menu_stocks_error);
                    $("#menu_stocks_error").html(result.menu_stocks_error);
                    $("#menu_image_error").html(result.menu_image_error);
                }
            },
            error: function(data) {
                alert('error');
            }
        })
        e.preventDefault();
    })
})
```

NOTE: So here, I used the javascript. Once the form is submitted it will direct to my js then the process will execute what ever is in the url: ....

This line of code below is checking if all fields is fill up.

```
if($this->form_validation->run('new-menu') == FALSE) {....
```

EDITED:

```
public function new_menu_form_submit()
{

    $config = array(
        'upload_path'   => 'uploads',
        'allowed_types' => 'jpg|png|PNG|JPG',
        'max_size'      => '2048', //25MB
        'encrypt_name'  => TRUE //encrypt filename
        );

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    if($this->form_validation->run('new-menu') == FALSE) {
        $error = [

            'menu_name_error'         => form_error('menu_name'),
            'menu_price_error'         => form_error('menu_price'),
            'menu_stocks_error'         => form_error('menu_stocks'),
            'menu_image_error'         => form_error('menu_image'),
        ];

        echo json_encode($error);
    }else{
        if($this->upload->do_upload('menu_image'))
        { // added
            $uppercase_menu_name = ucwords($this->input->post('menu_name'));

        $menu_name = preg_replace('/(.)(?=[A-Z])/u', '$2', $uppercase_menu_name);

             $uploaded_data = $this->upload->data(); // added

            $this->resize_uploaded_image($uploaded_data); //added

             $insert_menu = [
            'menu_name'               => clean_data($menu_name),
            'menu_price'               => $_POST['menu_price'],
            'menu_stocks'               => $_POST['menu_stocks'],
            'menu_image'               => $uploaded_data['file_name'], //edited 'menu_image'               => $this->upload->data('file_name'),

            'status'                    => "Active"
            ];
        } // added
        // $uploaded_data = $this->upload->data(); // remove
        // $this->resize_uploaded_image($uploaded_data); //remove


        // $uppercase_menu_name = ucwords($this->input->post('menu_name'));

        // $menu_name = preg_replace('/(.)(?=[A-Z])/u', '$2', $uppercase_menu_name);
        // $insert_menu = [
        //     'menu_name'               => clean_data($menu_name),
        //     'menu_price'               => $_POST['menu_price'],
        //     'menu_stocks'               => $_POST['menu_stocks'],
        //     'menu_image'               => $uploaded_data['file_name'], //edited 'menu_image'               => $this->upload->data('file_name'),

        //     'status'                    => "Active"
        // ];
        $this->Crud_model->insert('menu',$insert_menu);
        echo json_encode("success");
    }
}

 public function resize_uploaded_image($image_data)
    {
       $config = array(
            'image_library'     => 'gd2',
            'source_image'      => $image_data['uploads'], //uploaded imagepath
            'create_thumb'      => 'true',
            'width'             =>  575,
            'height'            =>  550,
        );

       $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);  
       $this->image_lib->resize(); 
    }
```

**In this part is inserting the data into my table**

```
$insert_menu = [
                'menu_name'               => clean_data($menu_name),
                'menu_price'               => $_POST['menu_price'],
                'menu_stocks'               => $_POST['menu_stocks'],
                'menu_image'               => $this->upload->data('file_name'),

                'status'                    => "Active"
            ];
```

Comment: You can't expect anyone to help you if you don't want to post you relevant code. You need to post the method you're file is being POSTED to in order for anyone to help. You question is also unclear, are you asking how you can resize an uploaded image?

Comment: Yess sorry my bad, I just edited my post. Yes

Comment: Are you using a script to submit this ? You have no form tag.

Comment: I edited again my post

Comment: Again, you are attempting to manipulate data that you have not uploaded to the server. Your form name field is `menu_image`, you NEED TO upload that first. See the first few lines of the answer below. There will never be an `uploads` index in `$this->upload->data();` I suggest you start using `var_dump()` as well as https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html

Comment: I just tried it and also the same. I edited again my post

Comment: I can't help you because I don't know what you're doing and it appears you don't either.

Answer (score 0):

You will first need to upload your image:

```
if($this->upload->do_upload('menu_image')){

    $uploaded_data = $this->upload->data(); //get the uploaded image information

    $this->resize_uploaded_image($uploaded_data); //send for resizing

    //example of saving IMAGE FILENAME TO DB, YOU CAN OPT TO SAVE FULLPATH
    $this->model->save_image_filename($uplodated_data['filename']);
   }else{
    ...
   }


//resizer
public function resize_uploaded_image($image_data)
{
   $config = array(
        'image_library'     => 'gd2',
        'source_image'      => $image_data['full_path'], //uploaded imagepath
        'create_thumb'      => 'true',
        'width'             =>  575,
        'height'            =>  550,
    );

   $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);  
   $this->image_lib->resize(); 
}
```

Of course you will add things like error handling. Please don't copy/paste as im sure there are tons of mistakes here, but this is a rough idea of the process.

Comment: No, the first part uploads the file to the server - the file must be on the server before you can do anything with it.  I generally think its silly to save images to databases.

Comment: I need it badly my friend. You're my last hope :(

Comment: full_path is where will I put the created thumb right?

Comment: Yes, wherever that path is will contain two images, an image at 575 X 550 and a thumbnail for that image.

Comment: I updated again my post, im having an error "Illegal string offset 'uploads'"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158569/discussion-between-angel-and-kisaragi).